# Reformat text file using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text data file that looks like below:

```
Day-Hour, 08188, 0, 08188, 1, (indicating the time is year 2008, julian day 188, between hour0 and hour1)
Receptor, A, (actual data begins)
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
Receptor, B,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
... (continue data for a total of 22 receptors, each receptor has 8 data values)

Day-Hour, 08188, 1, 08188, 2,
Receptor, A,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
Receptor, B,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
... (continue data for a total of 22 receptors, each receptor has 8 data values, but this is for hours 1 to 2)

...... (continue the same previous pattern for a total of 24 times)
```

I'd like to reformat it to be like this:

```
day, time, receptor, data1, data2, data3, ....data8  (header)
08188, 0, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
08188, 0, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
... (repeat the same hour for all 22 receptor sites)
08188, 1, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
08188, 1, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 
...(repeat the same hour for all 22 receptor sites)
...
...(repeat the same order 24 times)
```

I've managed to achieve the format I want through a couple of steps using combinations of awk and sed with something like below, but I feel it's kind of dumb to go through so many steps, and am hoping for experts' help to approach this in a much simpler step.  Your inputs are greatly appreciated!

```
(example steps:)
step1:  $ grep -v "Day-Hour" infile.txt > temp1.txt  # remove all Day-Hour lines, 
                                                     # as I know the order of the data
step2:  $ sed '/^$/d' temp1.txt > temp2.txt  # remove empty lines
step3:  $ awk 'ORS=NR%3" ":"\n"' temp2.txt > temp3.txt  #concatenate every 3 lines
step4:  $ (create a file, e.g. daytime.txt, with 2 fields (day and hour) with following content)
         08188, 0,
         (repeat 22 times)
         08188, 1,
         (repeat 22 times)
         .... (continue through hour 23)
step5:  $ paste daytime.txt temp3.txt > final.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure your `time` column is populated correctly? The first line `08188, 0, 08188, 1`  results in `0` time for both `A` and `B`? I would recommend better choice of sample data.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this through awk and sed commands. Actually, just awk should be sufficient. Read the manpage for more details.

Comment: This is an easy job for perl too.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my original post about what I really want to accomplish.  I've edited the question, and hopefully it's more clear to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do the job:

```
cat file
Day-Hour, 08188, 0, 08188, 1
Receptor, A,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
Receptor, B,
11, 12, 13, 14,
15, 16, 17, 18,
Receptor, C,
21, 22, 23, 24,
25, 26, 27, 28,

Day-Hour, 08188, 1, 08188, 2
Receptor, A,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
Receptor, B,
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 8,
```

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=", " -F", *|\n" 'BEGIN {print "day, time, receptor, data1, data2, data3,....data8"} {for (i=7;i<=NF;i+=13) print $2,$3,$i,$(i+2),$(i+3),$(i+4),$(i+5),$(i+7),$(i+8),$(i+9),$(i+10)}' file
day, time, receptor, data1, data2, data3,....data8
08188, 0, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
08188, 0, B, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
08188, 0, C, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
08188, 1, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
08188, 1, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

This will print all `Receptor`, if its `1` or `22`.

Comment: It looks like I accidentally left out the additional "," at the end of the Day-Hour line.  It should be like this "Day-Hour, 08188, 0, 08188, 1," in the first line.  And that seems to throw everything out of order with your code.  Sorry about that.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @Jung Adding a missing `,` is very simple.  You should be able to fix that. My code works fine with your data.  If it does not work with other data, you need to post it to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will join them up:

```
sed 's/$/,/;N;N;N;N;N;N;N; s/\n/ /g' foo.txt
```

into this:

> Day-Hour, 08188, 0, 08188, 1, Receptor, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   Receptor, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, Day-Hour, 08188, 1, 08188, 2,
>   Receptor, A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, Receptor, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>   8,

Then I got lazy in the repackaging:

```
... | awk '{ $1 = ""; $4 = ""; $5 = ""; print }' | sed -e 's/ \(.*\)  Receptor, \(A,.*\)Receptor, \(B, .*\)/\1\2\n\1\3/'
```

Which producd the desired output on my system.